# Getting Authorization error whild setting up warp 1.1.1.1 as device admin app

Tags: android, adb, admin, device, android-14

I am trying to set an app as a device owner/admin using the ADB shell command on a non-rooted Android device. The app package name is "com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone."

I have used the following ADB command:

```bash
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone/.com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone.MainActivity
```

However, I am encountering the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized
    ...
```

I do not want to root the device, and I understand the security implications. Are there any specific permissions or steps I am missing to set an app as a device owner/admin without rooting?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Tried this :

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone/.com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone.MainActivity
```

Error :

```
Exception occurred while executing 'set-device-owner':
java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized
    at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkCallAuthorization(Preconditions.java:247)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.setActiveAdmin(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3350)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.runSetDeviceOwner(DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.java:256)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.onCommand(DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.java:89)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.onShellCommand(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:9913)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1054)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:882)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub.onTransact(IDevicePolicyManager.java:6054)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1290)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1249)
```

Comment: The following blog post contains some details on that topic: https://medium.com/@codybrookshear/creating-an-android-device-owner-app-in-2023-b7e7b9fb3aca It mentions that the adb command only works for "test devices" (emulators?). For regular devices you need to register the app directly after factory reset.